# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.3

I've some problem with `decode` method in python 3.3.4. This is my code:

```
for line in open('file','r'):
    decodedLine = line.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    line = decodedLine.split('\t')
```

But I can't decode the line for this problem:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Yes, strings in Python 3.x no longer have the `decode` method - have a look at https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One *encodes* strings, and one *decodes* bytes.

You should read bytes from the file and decode them:

```
for lines in open('file','rb'):
    decodedLine = lines.decode('ISO-8859-1')
    line = decodedLine.split('\t')
```

Luckily `open` has an encoding argument which makes this easy:

```
for decodedLine in open('file', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1'):
    line = decodedLine.split('\t')
```

Answer (score 6):

`open` already decodes to Unicode in Python 3 if you open in text mode. If you want to open it as bytes, so that you can then decode, you need to open with mode 'rb'.

Answer (score 5):

After `PyJWT 2.0.0` version does not have a `decode` method, we are getting this error. We should freeze the below version to avoid this issue.

```
PyJWT==1.7.1
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me smoothly to read Chinese text in Python 3.6. First, convert str to bytes, and then decode them.

```
for l in open('chinese2.txt','rb'):
    decodedLine = l.decode('gb2312')
    print(decodedLine)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, use this mental model:

- *Encoding* is the process of converting a `str` object to a `bytes` object
- *Decoding* is the process of converting a `bytes` object to a `str` object

[image: Diagram]

You got the error `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`. If you need a `str`, there is no need to run `decode()` on it. Access the variable directly without calling `decode()`.