# read a file and try to remove all non UTF-8 chars

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode

I am trying to read a file and convert the string to a `UTF-8` string, in order to remove some non `utf-8` chars in the file string,

```
file_str = open(file_path, 'r').read()
file_str = file_str.decode('utf-8')
```

but I got the following error,

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Update: I tried the code as suggested by the answer,

```
file_str = open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

but it didn't eliminate the non `utf-8` chars, so how to remove them?

Comment: are you using python 3? In which case all strings are already unicode objects. You don't need to decode.

Comment: You are using Python 3; `open()` returned a file object that *already decoded to Unicode* for you. Python 3 `str` is the Unicode type, it has no `decode()` method because you can't decode Unicode any further.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['str' object has no attribute 'decode' in Python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125141/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-in-python3)

Comment: For coding matters...Please do mention Python version or tag it accordingly ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `.decode('utf8')` call. Your file data has *already* been decoded, because in Python 3 the `open()` call with text mode (the default) returned a file object that decodes the data to Unicode strings *for you*.

You probably *do* want to add the encoding to the `open()` call to make this explicit. Otherwise Python uses a system default, and that may not be UTF-8:

```
file_str = open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8').read()
```

For example, on Windows, the default codec is almost certainly going to be wrong for UTF-8 data, but you won't see the problem until you try to read the text; you'd find your have a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) as the UTF-8 data is decoded using CP1252 or a similar 8-bit codec.

See the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for further details.

Comment: This merely reads a UTF-8 encoded file.  The OP asks for a way to ignore non-UTF-8 characters while reading a file that contains some dirty characters.  This answer causes a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 80189: invalid continuation byte` when a dirty character is read.

Comment: @mareoraft: The OP never properly specified what they meant by *non-UTF8 characters*, which they wanted to remove after decoding. For files with **some** invalid data, you could use a different error handler, such as `errors='ignore'` or `errors='escape'` or `errors='surrogateescape'`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers

Comment: @mareoraft: do make 100% certain that the file is *meant* to be decodable as UTF-8. UTF-8 is resistant to some corruption, ignoring or replacing error values will not make subsequent correct data unreadable.

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
file_str = open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore').read()
```

, then non-UTF-8 characters will essentially be ignored.  Read the [`open()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for details.  The documentation has a section on the possible values for the `errors` parameter.