# Python package catboost plot_tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, catboost

I tried to plot the classifier tree with `catboost` in `jupyter notebook`.
However, it seems that it is not supported by `Python 3`.

I followed [this link](https://github.com/catboost/tutorials/blob/master/model_analysis/visualize_decision_trees_tutorial.ipynb) for plotting but got error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-117bb3853789> in <module>
     12 model.plot_tree(
     13     tree_idx=0,
---> 14     pool=pool # "pool" is required parameter for trees with one hot features
     15 )

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\catboost\core.py in plot_tree(self, tree_idx, pool)
   2386             for node_num in range(layer_size):
   2387                 if split_num >= 0:
-> 2388                     node_label = splits[split_num].decode('utf-8').replace('bin=', 'value>', 1)
   2389                     color = 'black'
   2390                     shape = 'ellipse'

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

It seems that string in `python 3` no longer has decode method.([HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125141/str-object-has-no-attribute-decode-in-python3))
Any suggestion?