# 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, decode

The function below first decodes the hexadecimal number into a string and then the map function applies the `ord` function to all the decoded values and give us a tuple but this decode function is giving this error `'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`:

```
def hex2rgb(hexcode):
    return tuple(map(ord, hexcode[1:].decode( )))
```

The code that I am writing is pertain to steganography here some part of the code which shows how the input to that function is generated:

```
binary = str2bin(message) + '1111111111111110' #converts string into binary and adds the delimeter at end to indicate message is ended

newData = [] #list to store the new pixels which contain the information

img = Image.open(filename)

if img.mode in ('RGBA'):
    img = img.convert('RGBA') #will convert the image into RGBA
    datas = img.getdata()  #will give all the pixel data
    digit = 0 #shows on which binary bit we are currently at      
    for item in datas:
        if (digit < len(binary)):
            newpix = encode(rgb2hex(item[0],item[1],item[2]),binary[digit])
            if newpix == None:
                newData.append(item)
            else:
                r, g, b = hex2rgb(newpix)
                newData.append((r,g,b,255))
                digit += 1
```

I don't understand why it is not decoding. I also tried `.decode('hex')` or `.decode(hex)` but it is still giving the error.

Comment: You can encode string and decode bytes. It seems like you might be trying to decode a string instead of byte, which is why you are get the error. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125141

Comment: What is your input for hexcode and what do you expect for your output?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @ zedfoxus my input is a hexadecimal which is generated in the middle of code

Comment: @ zedfoxus no no i am trying to decode bytes in hexadecimal

Comment: @Yatin my code is long in the middle i am generating a hexadecimal which i am converting passing to this function and getting the tuple back

Comment: We don't need the whole code. Just a [mre]. For example, how you're calling that function. with what input and what is the expected output

Comment: @ Tomerikoo i have edited the question again and also added the minimal code can you again please have a look

Comment: @zedfoxus  i have added the details

Comment: Above your `def` add `import base64`. Right after your `def` add `print(base64.b64encode(hexcode.encode('utf-8')))`. What output do you get?

Comment: @zedfoxus  its giving the same error

Comment: @zedfoxus  i looked into google and  found this method **codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex, 'hex'), 'base64').decode()** well its for base64 so i changed "base64" into "utf-8" and made it                   **r, g, b = tuple(map(ord,codecs.encode(codecs.decode(hex, 'hex'), 'utf-8').decode())**
   now whatever written in next line it gives it a syntax error

Comment: @hunter Did you add the `print` statement after `def`? You will continue to get an error but before the error, a base64 string would have printed. Can you add the base64 as a comment?

Comment: @hunter Can you update your question and include more information? What is the content of `message` variable? What is the content of `binary` variable? What does your `rgb2hex` function look like? Just above `r, g, b = hex2rgb(newpix)` line, do `print(base64.b64encode(newpix.encode('utf-8')))`. What does that print?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is incorrect. because you are trying to decode string that is already decoded. That's why the error is coming.

Comment: no its not decoded this function is written to decode the string. the input to function are bytes of hexadecimal

Comment: In my opinion it is more friendly and encouraging if you say something like "Your approach is incorrect..." rather than telling the person they are wrong.

Comment: @devdanke i apologize i didnt meant to be disrespectful towards you.